# what is the query to add new column with datatype and constraints?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to add a column to an existing table using the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE  `$tbname` ADD  $col_name $col_datatype, ADD CONSTRAINT $constraintName ($col_name);
```

what is wrong in this query?

Comment: You need to use backticks `\`` for the table name

Comment: Your constraint is incorrect - it is partial and does not set any restriction. It looks like common index definition.

Comment: *There is some syntax error in this* Always provide complere error message text.